# Patch attribute of mocked class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, magicmock, pytest-mock

I'm attempting to mock a class.

The class I'm attempting to mock looks like the following (lines have been removed for brevity):

```py
class Connection(object):
    """Connection.
    """

    def __init__(self, base_url=None, creds=None, user_agent=None):
        self.clients = ClientFactory(self)
```

As you can see, it has a property called `clients`.

My method under test:

```py
    def _auth(self, credentials):
        connection = Connection(base_url=f'https://someurl.com', creds=credentials)

        return connection.clients
```

My unit test looks like this:

```py
@patch('connection.Connection.__init__')
def test_deploy(patched_connection, fs):
    patched_connection.return_value = None
    patched_connection.clients = None

    # Do some stuff
```

The question is... how do I set the `clients` property in my test as the method under test requires it to be set?  (I can set it to `None`, but I just need to be able to set it.)

With the current code, my application returns the error:

```py
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'clients'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to patch the `Connection` class itself, not the `__init__` method:

```py
@patch('connection.Connection')
def test_deploy(patched_connection, fs):
    connection_object = MagicMock()
    patched_connection.return_value = connection_object
    connection_object.clients = None
    sut = Auth()  # create the tested object (Auth is a placeholder here)
    sut._auth('')  # call the tested function

    # test for how `Connection` was constructed 
    patched_connection.assert_called_once_with(
        base_url='https://someurl.com', creds='')
```

You patch the `Connection` class, and by setting `return_value` you set the `Connection` instance mock. Now you can set the wanted attributes in that instance.

Note that checking for the `__init__` call actually means to check for the instance creation call, so you can use the `Connection` mock for that.

This is presuming that you don't want to test `Connection` itself, of course, and that `_auth` belongs to another class (here called `Auth`).

Comment: That works, but another question...previously I had the assertion `patched_connection.assert_called_with(...)`.  How do I update the assertion so that I can ensure the `__init__` is called with the expected params?  Thanks!

Comment: I adapted the answer with the needed assertion - please check!